# ¿Cómo pasar valores de Map<Strind Dynamic>a variable String?

Tags: flutter, map

En el siguiente código como logro capturar los valor de type y de count en variables tipo String

```
class PortalInfo {
  final String name;
  final List<String> domains;
  final List<Object> noOfArtcles;

PortalInfo({
  required this.name,
  required this.domains,
  required this.noOfArtcles
});

factory PortalInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
  return PortalInfo(
     name: parsedJson['name'],
     domains : parsedJson['domains'],
     noOfArtcles : parsedJson ['noOfArticles']
  );
 }

}

Map<String, dynamic> _portaInfoMap = {
  "name": "Vitalflux.com",
  "domains": ["Data Science", "Mobile", "Web"],
  "noOfArticles": [{"type": "data science", "count": 50}, {"type": "web", "count": 75}]
};
```

He intentado esto pero no me funciona, alguna sugerencia

```
String tipo = portalInfo.noOfArtcles[0]['type'];
String cantidad = portalInfo.noOfArtcles[0]['count'];
```

Answer (score 1):

no vas a poder acceder a `noOfArtcles` de esa forma

```
String tipo = portalInfo.noOfArtcles[0]['type'];
String cantidad = portalInfo.noOfArtcles[0]['count'];
```

ya que está declarado como `Object` asi que debe castearlo a tipo `Map`

```
Map map = portalInfo.noOfArtcles[0] as Map;
String tipo = map['type'];
String cantidad = map['count'];
```

o sino modificar la el tipo de variable en la clase

```
  final List<Map<String,dynamic>> noOfArtcles;
```

Answer (score 0):

`portalInfo` es un mapa, por ende debes acceder directamente a la `key`:

```
String tipo = portalInfo["noOfArtcles"][0]["type"]
```

de igual forma para la cantidad

```
 String tipo = portalInfo["noOfArtcles"][0]["count"]
```

Mi error... acabé de revisar bien tu pregunta y es cierto lo que dices, complementando la otra respuesta, tu ya tienes un método factory en la clase modelo, te dejo un ejemplo más practico de como implementarlo:

Yo cree un pequeño `testController` para poder realizar la prueba con tu data

```
    class TestController {
  Future<void> testData() async {
    String tipo = "";
    String cantidad = "";

    //todo -> data de tipo Map<String, dynamic>(ya declarada en la clase modelo)
    final data = portaInfoMap;

    //todo -> aquí usamos el método factory para poder settear los datos del modelo y tener un acceso más rapido y eficaz
    final dataPortal = PortalInfo.fromJson(data);

    if (dataPortal.noOfArtcles.isNotEmpty) {
      //todo -> aquí casteamos la data, ya que luego no te reconocerá el ["type"] y ["count"]
      final list = dataPortal.noOfArtcles as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;

      //todo -> aquí realizo un ciclo for para no estar asignando item x item
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        tipo = list[i]["type"];
        cantidad = list[i]["count"].toString();

        debugPrint("tipo: $tipo \ncantidad: $cantidad");
      }
    }
  }
```

}

output:

```
flutter: tipo: data science
flutter:  cantidad: 50
flutter: tipo: web
flutter:  cantidad: 75
```

**TENER EN CUENTA QUE A *_portaInfoMap* LE QUITÉ *_* PARA QUE NO SEA PRIVADO Y PODER ACCEDER A ESA DATA DE EJEMPLO**

Comment: Hola @Jonathan Perez, gracias por responder. Probe tu sugerencia, al colocar la linea como me sugieres **String tipo = portalInfo["noOfArtcles"][0]["type"]** me genera un error en esa linea  **The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'PortalInfo'.**

Comment: Si @Isabel ya actualicé la respuesta, disculpa.